# How can I be notified when a control becomes key? I want t o have my custom warning popover NSWindow autohide and show; only the hide part works

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a custom NSWindow subclass that's used to display a pop-out warning on NSTextFields. I want the warning to automatically hide when the NSTextField loses key status, and to show again when it gains key. So I have

```
    self.onBegin = [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:NSControlTextDidBeginEditingNotification
        object:self.textfield
        queue:nil
        usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note){
            [self orderFront:self];
        }];
    self.onEnd = [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:NSControlTextDidEndEditingNotification
        object:self.textfield
        queue:nil
        usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note){
            [self orderOut:self];
        }];
```

`onEnd` works fine: the custom window hides itself when I tab away from the text field or do something else, etc. But `onBegin` doesn't seem to fire until I start actually changing the contents of the text field.

Is there some other option I can use? Should I not be using notifications for this, or is there some API (must be 10.7+) that I don't know about? Thanks.

Comment: That (or rather, its Mac equivalent) still only triggers when I start typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Key-Value Observing (KVO) to monitor the `firstResponder` property of the window containing the text fields. When you get notified that the first responder has changed, you can check if it's one of the text fields you're interested in. Note, though, that the window's `firstResponder` won't be the text field itself, it will be the text *view* that serves as the field editor for the text field. To determine which text field the field editor serves, you check the field editor's `delegate`.

See [Cocoa Event Handling Guide: Event Handling Basics – Determining First-Responder Status](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventHandlingBasics/EventHandlingBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH5-SW23).

```
if ([window.firstResponder isKindOfClass:[NSTextView class]] &&
    [window fieldEditor:NO forObject:nil] != nil)
{
    NSTextField *field = [window.firstResponder delegate];
    // Do something with 'field', which is the text field that has focus
}
```

Comment: Hm,... either I'm doing something wrong somewhere, or the `[[self.parent firstResponder] delegate]` is always nil? Either way this does get me the message I want at the right time, so that's closer...

Comment: What is `self.parent`? Is it the window *containing* the text fields? Are you sure that it is not itself `nil`? Also, are you using a custom field editor?

Comment: Yes, it's the window containing the text fields (I checked). It is not nil, nor is the first responder. The field editor is not custom, but I did modify it to turn off autocorrect. I also checked to make sure the instances of the field editor are the same; they are. Only the delegate pointer is nil (as is the delegate of the field editor if I grab it from there).

Comment: `tv = (NSTextView *) [window fieldEditor:YES forObject:nil]; [tv setEnabledTextCheckingTypes:0]; [tv setAutomaticDashSubstitutionEnabled:NO]; [tv setAutomaticSpellingCorrectionEnabled:NO]; [tv setAutomaticTextReplacementEnabled:NO];`

Comment: In what context do you have the above code for modifying the field editor? I wonder if requesting it and passing `nil` for the object is clearing the delegate. I would recommend that you do this in a different way. Option 1: use a custom subclass of `NSTextFieldCell` and override `-setUpFieldEditorAttributes:` to, well, set the field editor's attributes. Option 2: use a custom window subclass and override `-fieldEditor:forObject:`. Call through to `super` and then, depending on `anObject`, modify it before returning it.

Comment: The field editor modifications are created as part of the window creation process. Wouldn't the nil in my observer code also have the same effect, though? Whatever the case, I can try the override NSWindow option and report back how that goes.

Comment: Update: nope, subclassing NSWindow didn't fix it. I also disabled the changes entirely; still a nil delegate.

Comment: Very strange. It's clearly documented that the field editor's `delegate` will be the text field. What is the window's `firstResponder`? What is it's field editor? Are they the same object?

Comment: Yep; they're the same. I'm actually starting to think the delegate simply isn't set when the KVO observer is signaled. I'm not sure how to check (dispatch_async()?).

Comment: Yep, that was it. I'm now observing the field editor's delegate instead, and everything works correctly. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad you found the reason. I'm not sure it's safe to observe the delegate. It's not documented as KVO-compliant. A delayed check like you suggested may be safest.